# How to completely close the class and open new class

Tags: android, camera

I'm coding a camera application which has a startup screen.

My problem is how to completely close the startup class and open the camera class?
Calling `finish();` don't work on the system.

I would like to close the first or startup class to save more memory space on the gadget.

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by open camera class? Are you trying to open the default camera app or you are calling a camera service?

If your answer is second one then i hope you are having some surface view at some place, as camera service needs that.

If your answer is first one then its ok to close your startup class.

Did you try using

```
(StartupActivity.this).finish();
```

if this doesn't help then please post some relevant part of your code here for our  better understanding.